# WDIO is entering each characters on login screen very slowly when opened in IE 11

Tags: timeout, mocha.js, internet-explorer-11, wdio-v5

With the use of WDIO, I am trying to automate the login screen of an application developed in ReactJs & Node.js. It takes a pause of 4-5 seconds after entering each character. 
Because of this, a timeout happens before the "Sign In" button is clicked and I am getting the following error.

> Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>   (E:\Jigs\WDIO_React\specs\loginReactIE.spec.js)

I am still fairly new in using WDIO and I am clueless about how this could be resolved.

I have the following devDependencies in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/crossbrowsertesting-service": "^6.0.8",
    "@wdio/firefox-profile-service": "^6.0.7",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.22.4",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.18.7",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.0.8",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.22.4",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.20.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chromedriver": "^80.0.1",
    "geckodriver": "^1.19.1",
    "iedriver": "^3.14.1",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "selenium-standalone": "^6.17.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2",
    "wdio-geckodriver-service": "^1.0.3",
    "wdio-iedriver-service": "^0.1.0",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.12"
  }
```

The IE 11 version is 11.1098.17763.0
And it's 64-bit.

I read here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver that I need to set a registry entry for IE11 and got it done. Still, I have no luck.

Could anybody please help me with how I could fix the slowness in entering the values on the login screen so that timeout could be avoided?

Here's my loginReactIE.page.js:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;

class loginReactPageIE {
  // Locate ClientId
  get userName() {return $("input#email")}

  // Locate Password
  get password() {return $("input#password")}

  // Locate "Sign In" button
  get signIn() {return $("#login button.btn")}

  enterUsername(clientId) {
    expect(this.userName.isDisplayed()).to.equal(true);
    this.userName.addValue(clientId);
  }

  enterPassword(pw) {
    expect(this.password.isDisplayed()).to.equal(true);
    this.password.addValue(pw);
  }

  submit() {
    expect(this.signIn.isDisplayed()).to.equal(true);
    this.signIn.click();
  }
}
module.exports = new loginReactPageIE();
```

And here's loginReactIE.spec.js:

```
const loginReactPageIE = require("../pageobjects/loginReactIE.page");
const assert = require("assert");
var expect = require("chai").expect;

describe("Loign as client and check profile", function() {
  it("login is successful with valid credentials", function() {
    try {
      browser.url("/");
      browser.setWindowSize(1900, 1000);

      loginReactPageIE.enterUsername("jigs_test");      
      loginReactPageIE.enterPassword("TestPass1@");      
      loginReactPageIE.submit();
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
    browser.pause(30000);
  });
```

Comment: I suggest you try to post your automation code so that we can see how you are entering the value in the element. If you are using SendKeys() then try to set the value of that element. so whole text gets entered together. It may help to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Deepak-MSFT. I've edited my question and added the code.

Comment: Try to create an object variable for username and password field and then try to click on it using code and then try to set its value like password.setValue("password"). You can try to test this suggestion on your side and let us know about your testing result.